# Web Mercator formulas spitting out blatantly incorrect values

Tags: math, web, radians, mercator

EDIT: I simply forgot to convert degrees to radians.

I've been trying to convert some latitude and longitude coordinates to Web Mercator pixel form, and the formulas listed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator#Formulas) are spitting out blatantly incorrect values.  Wikipedia says the world coordinates go from 0 to 256 on the X and Y axis when not scaled.  The formulas listed on the wikipedia page easily spit out values a large amount above 256.

For example, a longitude of 87.7494 radians, when plugged into the formula for the X-axis, produces 3703.23219542.  This value is way above 256.

Try it yourself: (128 / pi) * (2 ^ 0) * (87.7494 + pi)

Comment: Why is 87.7 radians an acceptable input? Do you know what that is in degrees?

Comment: @DouglasZare I did not notice that, thank you for answering my question.  I forgot to convert degrees to radians.

Answer (score 0):

By converting degrees to radians, I have remedied the problem.